# Parallel Processing Collision Pairs

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, collision

I am writing some code for parallel processing of collisions, the expected result would be to have an acceleration for each thread, but I'm not getting any acceleration on the data processing because I have a critical section inside `parallel_reduce()` and I believe its serializing too much the access to the objects. This is how the code looks:

```
do {
    totalVel = 0.;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < bodyContact.size(); i++) {
        totalVel += bodyContact.at(i).bodyA()->parallel_reduce();
        totalVel += bodyContact.at(i).bodyB()->parallel_reduce();
    }
} while (totalVel >= 0.00001);
```

Is there any way to gain more speed by making it parallel or the serialization of access is too much?

Observations:

- **bodyA()** and **bodyB()** are objects that repeat themselves a lot inside the bodyContact container.
- For now `parallel_reduce()` only does one multiplication (the critical section), but will get more complex.

```
double parallel_reduce(){
    #pragma omp critical
        this->vel_ *= 0.99;
        return vel_.length();
    }
```

Actual timings:

- serial, 25.635
- parallel, 123.559

Comment: if `parallel_reduce()` is your bottleneck, then it's what you've got to work on. Maybe post the body of it and people can help. There's no secret weapon here!

Comment: A parallel loop over critical regions is basically just a serial loop with a lot of added overheads, and it doesn't surprise me that it's slower.  Tell us more about the this->vels in bodyContact.at(i).bodyA() and .bodyB(). Are they all independent, or will some As and some Bs overlap?

Comment: They will overlap a lot. And the actual code for the parallel_reduce() is not as heavy as it should to make any difference, is there any other way to make that code slower so that the difference can be noticed?

Comment: Can you tell me more about how this loop proceeds; I'm guessing that `i` is the collision number, and bodyA() and bodyB() could be any two random bodies in the simulation?   Is it true that there may be multi-body collisions (eg, body #7 and #18 both colliding with body #11 at the same time)?   Or will any body appear in this only once?   What fraction of the body are colliding at The reason for these questions is that the only way to make this loop faster is to arrange it so that as many bodies as possible can be updated at once independently.

Answer (score 1):

There is always cost of using OpenMP constructs, so avoid using a parallel inside a loop, following the implementation it could launch at each time new threads, instead of rewaking the previous launched threads.

In fact, if bodyContact.size() is small and the do {} while in number of step is big and parallel_reduce is very quick is very hard to have scalability with just a few OpenMP pragma.

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(totalVel) shared(bodyContact)
{
   do {
       totalVel = 0.;
       #pragma omp for reduce(+:totalVel)
       for (unsigned long i = 0; i < bodyContact.size(); i++) {
          totalVel += bodyContact.at(i).bodyA()->parallel_reduce();
          totalVel += bodyContact.at(i).bodyB()->parallel_reduce();
       }
   } while (totalVel >= 0.00001);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above is likely not only slower, but very likely wrong; all the threads are trying to update the same totalVel.  Tonnes of race conditions, but also contention, cache invalidation, etc.

Assuming the `parallel_reduce()` stuff is ok, you'd like something more like

```
do {
    totalVel = 0.;
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(bodyContact) reduction(+:totalVel)
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < bodyContact.size(); i++) {
        totalVel += bodyContact.at(i).bodyA()->parallel_reduce();
        totalVel += bodyContact.at(i).bodyB()->parallel_reduce();
    }
} while (totalVel >= 0.00001);
```

which will do the [reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Reduction) on `totalVel` correctly.

Comment: Yes, but its still slower than the serial version. 


    double parallel_reduce()
    {
    #pragma omp critical
        this->vel_ *= 0.99;
        return vel_.length();
    }


That is how parallel_reduce() looks like, any advice on making the parallel version faster?

Comment: Well, then Cory Nelson is right, and `parallel_reduce()` (and possibly the critical) is the bottleneck, and you'll have to show that code.  We here can only work with the code we can see.